# Customised Repository with JpaRepository not working Spring boot 3.2.3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria, spring-boot-3

I am trying to implement the custom repository with JpaRepository in spring boot 3.2.3 by following the official documentation but is not working as expected.

My Repository Interface:

```java
package com.test.accounts.repository;

import com.test.accounts.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface AccountsRepository extends JpaRepository<Accounts, Long>, AccountsRepositoryCustom {

}
```

My Customised Account repository:

```java
package com.test.accounts.dao;

public interface AccountsRepositoryCustom {

    void myCustomFindQuery();

}
```

Implementation of Customised repository:

```java
package com.test.accounts.dao.impl;

import com.test.accounts.dao.AccountsRepositoryCustom;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AccountsRepositoryImpl implements AccountsRepositoryCustom {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountsRepositoryImpl.class);
    
    @Override
    public void myCustomFindQuery() {
        log.debug("sharedAccountsMethod");
    }

}
```

Account Service code:

```java
package com.test.accounts.service.impl;

import com.test.accounts.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Random;

@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements IAccountService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountServiceImpl.class);
    
    private final AccountsRepository accountsRepository;
    
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    private Accounts createNewAccount(Customer customer) {
        Accounts newAccount = new Accounts();
        newAccount.setCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId());
        long randomAccNumber = 1000000000L + new Random().nextInt(900000000);
    
        newAccount.setAccountNumber(randomAccNumber);
        newAccount.setAccountType(AccountConstants.SAVINGS);
        newAccount.setBranchAddress(AccountConstants.ADDRESS);
        newAccount.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        newAccount.setCreatedBy("Test");
        return newAccount;
    }
    
    public AccountServiceImpl(AccountsRepository accountsRepository, CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.accountsRepository = accountsRepository;
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param customerDto {@link CustomerDto}
     */
    @Override
    public void createAccount(CustomerDto customerDto) {
        log.info("LOGSSSSSSSS");
        Customer customer = CustomerMapper.mapToCustomer(customerDto, new Customer());
        this.customerRepository.findByMobileNumber(customerDto.getMobileNumber()).ifPresent(cust -> {
            throw new CustomerAlreadyExistsException(
                    "Customer already registered with given mobileNumber:" + cust.getMobileNumber());
        });
        customer.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        customer.setCreatedBy("Test");
        Customer savedCustomer = this.customerRepository.save(customer);
        this.accountsRepository.save(createNewAccount(savedCustomer));
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```java
package com.test.accounts.controller;

import com.test.accounts.*;
import org.springframework.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/api", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public class AccountsController {

    private final IAccountService accountService;
    
    public AccountsController(IAccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "customer", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<GenericAllResponseDto> createCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto) {
        this.accountService.createAccount(customerDto);
        GenericAllResponseDto responseDto = new GenericAllResponseDto();
        responseDto.setStatusCode(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.CREATED.value()));
        responseDto.setStatusMsg(HttpStatus.CREATED.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(responseDto);
    }

}
```

but I run my project it gives me the error:

```
2024-03-17T14:43:29.234+05:30 ERROR 75477 --- \[accounts\] \[  restartedMain\] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountsRepository' defined in com.course.accounts.repository.AccountsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void com.course.accounts.dao.AccountsRepositoryCustom.myCustomFindQuery(); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.course.accounts.dao.AccountsRepositoryCustom.myCustomFindQuery(); No property 'myCustomFindQuery' found for type 'Accounts'
at 
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.course.accounts.dao.AccountsRepositoryCustom.myCustomFindQuery(); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.course.accounts.dao.AccountsRepositoryCustom.myCustomFindQuery(); No property 'myCustomFindQuery' found for type 'Accounts'

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.course.accounts.dao.AccountsRepositoryCustom.myCustomFindQuery(); No property 'myCustomFindQuery' found for type 'Accounts'
```

- As custom repository is not the part of JPA repo why its trying to create query from method name?

I have tried the same way it was mentioned in this spring boot official [DOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html)

- is it a bug in spring-data-jpa or spring boot?

Comment: Should the custom interface extent the AccountsRepository?  I see no relationship between those interfaces as written.  Never assume it's a bug in Spring.  The problems start and end with you.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for replying, answer to your response is that I am trying to provide my customised repository using following JdbcTemplate or EntityManager or may be raw JDBC while also need the JPARepository methods i.e findById(), findByIdAndName() etc.

I have also attached the official doc link in post, linking it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html) again!

Comment: Yes.   You are not doing it correctly.  Do you understand what I suggested?  If yes, try it.  If not, go read about Java interfaces.